# SQL server variable to SSIS and mail formatting issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sendmail

```
set @mail_Body = 'Here is one line of text ' 
                +@CRLF+ 'Some Text          : '   //space not matching ":" in 4th line
                +@CRLF+  // Not working
                +@CRLF+ N'Below is some data: ' + N' ' + N' ' + ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')
```

Am setting the mail body in sql server and assigning this variable to result set in SSIS and sending mail. But am not getting the correct format as i commented in the code.

Even i tried `SET mail_Body ='<html><body><H3>Contact Info</H3></body></html>`   but it didnt worked either

What is the correct way to do this with sql to ssis and mail ?

Comment: What have you assigned to @CRLF ?

Comment: You are using sp_send_dbmail, yes?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for and don't know whether the below snippet would serve the purpose

```
DECLARE @mail_Body NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @CRLF NCHAR(2)= CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SET @mail_Body = 'Here is one line of text ' 
+@CRLF+ 'Some Text          : '   --space not matching ":" in 4th line
+@CRLF+  -- Not working
+@CRLF+ N'Below is some data: ' + N' ' + N' ' + ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')
PRINT @mail_Body
```

Comment: PRINT will work fine. But same variable send to SSIS and then mail wont display properly

Comment: Have you added both 
Line Feed – LF 10 (decimal)
Return    – CR 13 (decimal)

Comment: Yes. I added first time itself